# Regarding Spark Dataframereader jdbc

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question regarding Mechanics of Spark Dataframereader. I will appreciate if anybody can help me. Let me explain the Scenario here

I am creating a DataFrame from Dstream like this. This in Input Data

```
 var config = new HashMap[String,String]();
        config += ("zookeeper.connect" ->zookeeper);        
        config += ("partition.assignment.strategy" ->"roundrobin");
        config += ("bootstrap.servers" ->broker);
        config += ("serializer.class" -> "kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder");
        config += ("group.id" -> "default"); 

        val lines =  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc,config.toMap,Set(topic)).map(_._2)

        lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>

                if(!rdd.isEmpty()){

                    val rddJson = rdd.map { x => MyFunctions.mapToJson(x) }       
                    



                           
                    val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(ssc.sparkContext)

                    val rddDF = sqlContext.read.json(rddJson)

                    rddDF.registerTempTable("inputData")
            
                   

 val dbDF = ReadDataFrameHelper.readDataFrameHelperFromDB(sqlContext, jdbcUrl, "ABCD","A",numOfPartiton,lowerBound,upperBound)
```

Here is the code of ReadDataFrameHelper

```
def readDataFrameHelperFromDB(sqlContext:HiveContext,jdbcUrl:String,dbTableOrQuery:String,
            columnToPartition:String,numOfPartiton:Int,lowerBound:Int,highBound:Int):DataFrame={

        val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url = jdbcUrl, table = dbTableOrQuery,
                columnName = columnToPartition,
                lowerBound = lowerBound,
                upperBound = highBound,
                numPartitions = numOfPartiton,
                connectionProperties = new java.util.Properties()
                )
                
            jdbcDF  

    }
```

Lastly I am doing a Join like this

```
 val joinedData = rddDF.join(dbDF,rddDF("ID") === dbDF("ID")
                                 && rddDF("CODE") === dbDF("CODE"),"left_outer")
                        .drop(dbDF("code"))
                        .drop(dbDF("id"))
                        .drop(dbDF("number"))
                        .drop(dbDF("key"))
                        .drop(dbDF("loaddate"))
                        .drop(dbDF("fid"))
joinedData.show()
```

My input DStream will have 1000 rows and data will contains million of rows. So when I do this join, will spark load all the rows from database and read those rows or will this just read those specific rows from DB which have the `code,id` from the input DStream

Comment: It will load complete table. There is no predicate push down here.

Comment: Does the `columnToPartition` need to have **unique-values**? I can't foresee a case where using a **non-unique** column would violate correctness of read operation (apart from unevenly sized tasks)

Comment: @y2k-shubham The problem was not correctness. It was that Dataframe was reding the whole table and doing the calculations.

Comment: I have still moved to a new project. i dont know how i fixed this issue after two years

Comment: **@Saurabh Sharma** pardon me but I didn't intend to clarify your question; rather I was asking my own doubt: in the method `spark.read.jdbc(..)`, does the column `columnName` need to have **UNIQUE constraint** on RDBMS side? I always felt that this should be required but upon a closer look at docs and examples and deeper thinking, I felt that this isn't really required. Actually my source of confusion was that column `columnName` should be **indexed** to leverage advantage of parallelization and since UNIQUE columns are indexed, i thought that.. But now I'm clear. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

As specified by  zero323, i have also confirmed that data will be read full from the table. I checked the DB session logs and saw that whole dataset is getting loaded.

Thanks zero323